# Тень кнопки CSS

Tags: css, button

Как наиболее просто сделать так, чтобы верхняя тень плавно исчезала после отжатия кнопки. Не хочется создавать отдельный элемент. Можно ли это сделать через `box-shadow`?

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6jftod7u/)

```css
.btn {
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 0 blue;
}

.btn span {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #3194c6;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}

.btn:active span {
  transform: translate(0, 6px);
  box-shadow: 0 -5px 0 blue;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn"><span>Press this!</span></a>
```

Comment: Сделать тоже самое, но без тега `span`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPD. Варианты со ссылкой без спана внутри. Меняются `box-shadow` и `top`. (Изменение `transform` рассогласоывается с изменением `box-shadow`, и кажется, что тень под кнопкой дёргается.)

Во втором случае используем две тени, чтобы каждая менялась в том же темпе, что и `top`. (Если менять одну тень с `6px` до `-6px`, то они будет меняться вдвое быстрее, и получится некрасиво.)

```css
.btn {
  background: #3194c6;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 0 0 blue;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  top: 0px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.btn:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 blue;
  top: 6px;
}

.btn-2 {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 0 0 blue, 0 0 0 0 blue;
}

.btn-2:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 blue, 0 -6px 0 0 blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">Press this!</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-2">Press this!</a>
```